# OS X, SSH: use different private key files for different servers

Tags: ssh, openssh, private-key

I want to use different private key files to connect to different SSH servers (`ssh://git-server:port/repository`). How to manage that? SSH seems to assume the private key file in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's why there's the `-i` option:

> `-i identity_file`
>
> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or DSA authentication is read.  The default is `~/.ssh/identity` for protocol version 1, and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_dsa` for protocol version 2.
>
> Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple `-i` options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).

If you want to make this permanent, you need to [setup your SSH config file](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1625/Using+a+SSH+Config+File) and set the according [`IdentityFile` option](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5).

> `IdentityFile`
>
> Specifies a file from which the user's DSA, ECDSA or DSA authentication identity is read. […]

If you see a dialog similar to this:

[image]

You need to enter your **user password** for your OS X account. Not your key passphrase, or the remote SSH password. This is because they identity hasn't been stored in the keychain.

According to [this tutorial](http://om4.com.au/ssh-rsa-key-pairs-passphrases-leopard/), the following command should add them appropriately:

```
ssh-add -K
```

Comment: OK, I've done that now, but when trying to log in, OS X asks in a separate dialog for the *password* instead of *passphrase*. I'm entering the correct passphrase for the private key files, but it still can't log in. Any further ideas?

Comment: If it asks you for the *password*, that's the SSH password on the remote machine, not the passphrase for the key.

Comment: No, no, it asks me for the *password* for my private key file - at least that's what the dialog is saying. BTW, without the *passphrase* SSH could not do anything on the remote machine.

Comment: Hm. I'm not an expert in SSH, I have to admit. What is that dialog saying exactly?

Comment: I've configured `IdentityFile = ~/secret/pk-file` in `~/.ssh/config` and invoke `ssh myserver`. The occurring dialog says `Enter your password for the SSH key "pk-file".`, shows a `Password` input field and two checkboxes (`Show password` and `Remember passwod in my keychain`). I'm entering the correct passphrase, but I'm asked 2 more times and then SSH aborts with `RSA host key for IP address '1.2.3.4' not in list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).` (1.2.3.4 is dummy).

Comment: Oh, this is your Mac OS X Keychain. See my updated answer.

Comment: I've found that my Mac will never accept my ssh key password on the first 2 tries! I always have to enter my password 3 times when presented with the password prompt shown above.

Comment: When I do this it sais "Saving password to keychain failed"

Comment: Updated answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250572/148051

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish this is with a ssh config file.

cat ~/.ssh/config

```
HOST *  
     USER root
```

You can also specify certain subdomains use certain users. Useful if your laptop travels between networks.

```
HOST 192.168.*.*
     USER homeuser

HOST 10.2.*.*
     USER workuser
```

You could even configure by domains, and use different ssh keys for different domains.

```
HOST *.microsoft.com
     USER bill
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/microsoft/id_rsa

HOST *.apple.com
     USER steve
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/apple/id_rsa
```